# How to suppress output of <p> tags in a views2 field output?

Tags: views, theming

I've determined that I have an extra blank line above/below a field as output by views2.  The generated html code examination shows a set of paragraph tags enclosing the field.  I can find nowhere within this view to suppress that output.  Is there a way either within views2 or via some css attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You could go through the effort of [overriding the template](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/using-theme) for that field, or you could just target the p tag with css and set the margins to 0px.

Views adds pretty granular classes to every field and row to make it easy to target.